Offcanvas with react and preeline is not working
I am using preeline with react and trying to open offcanvas by clicking details button in the table.
I can't open the Offcanvas when I click the button.
It is my button component with offcanvas
import { IButton } from '@interfaces/Interfaces';

const Button: React.FC<IButton> = ({ labelButton,id, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <button
        {...props} data-hs-overlay={`#${id}`}>
        {labelButton}
      </button>

      <div id={id} className="hs-overlay hs-overlay-open:translate-x-0 hidden translate-x-full fixed top-0 end-0 transition-all duration-300 transform h-full max-w-xs w-full z-[80] bg-white border-s dark:bg-neutral-800 dark:border-neutral-700" >
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center py-3 px-4 border-b dark:border-neutral-700">
          <h3 className="font-bold text-gray-800 dark:text-white">
            Offcanvas title
          </h3>
          <button type="button" 
          className="flex justify-center items-center size-7 text-sm font-semibold rounded-full border border-transparent text-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 disabled:opacity-50 disabled:pointer-events-none dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-neutral-700" 
          data-hs-overlay={`#${id}`}>
            <span className="sr-only">Close modal</span>
            <svg className="flex-shrink-0 size-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth="2" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
              <path d="M18 6 6 18"></path>
              <path d="m6 6 12 12"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="p-4">
          <p className="text-gray-800 dark:text-neutral-400">
            Some text as placeholder. In real life you can have the elements you have chosen. Like, text, images, lists, etc.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Button;

it is my parent component:
{items.map((quote: any, index: number) => (
            <tr key={index} className='odd:bg-white even:bg-gray-100 dark:odd:bg-neutral-900 dark:even:bg-neutral-800'>
              <td className='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-800 dark:text-neutral-200 font-semibold'>{quote.tradiesName}</td>
              <td className='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-800 dark:text-neutral-200'>{quote.businessName}</td>
              <td className='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-800 dark:text-neutral-200'>{quote.phoneNumber??'No data available'}</td>
              <td className='px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-800 dark:text-neutral-200'><Button {...detailsButton} id={quote.id}/></td>
            </tr>
          ))}

